# $WshShell->Run() php

Tags: php

My question is about `$WshShell->Run()` php method, integrating it with swfTools (converting file pdf to swf). When I run this command in php it gives me a blank page and does not convert the file into swf. But when I run it directly in cmd it converts the file. Please tell me why the error is occuring?

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
oExec = $WshShell->Run("d:\SWFTools\pdf2swf.exe C:\wamp\www\flex\zubair.pdf -o d:\zubair.swf", 0, true);
?>
```

**direcly in cmd**

```
d:\SWFTools\pdf2swf.exe C:\wamp\www\flex\zubair.pdf -o d:\zubair.swf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `$` sign in the `oExec` variable declaration. And I think you have to escape the backslashes in your command.

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("D:\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe C:\\wamp\\www\\flex\\zubair.pdf -o D:\\zubair.swf", 0, true);
```

Comment: Thank you Smott for resolving my problem